# How to use ion-radio with formControlName

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I'm using ion-radio compoenent of ionic 4 in my projetct I want to set the visiteur option selected by default  I put [checked]="true" but it doesnt work:

```
 <ion-list style="margin-top: 5px;" class="ion-padding">
        <ion-radio-group  (ionChange)="onChangeHandler($event)"  formControlName="userType">



          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="penblue">Entreprise</ion-label>
            <ion-radio color="penbluegrig" slot="start" value="Entreprise"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="penblue">Transporteur</ion-label>
            <ion-radio color="penbluegrig"  slot="start" value="Transporteur"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label color="penblue">Visiteur</ion-label>
            <ion-radio color="penbluegrig"  slot="start" [checked]='true'  value="Visiteur"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
```

How to resolve this problem.? please?

Comment: Did you try just adding `checked` without any value to the Visiteur radio option?

Comment: Since you using reactive form you can set userType control to true

Comment: it doesnt work..